# Assigning Carts to User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, shopping-cart

I'm trying to build a shopping cart that is assigned to a user. What happens now though is when an item is added to the shopping cart, it's added for every user. It seems every user is using the same cart and I can't get users from being able to add to to other users carts. How can I make it so that each user has a unique cart and can only add to theirs?

Here's what I have:

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy, :show]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart

  # GET /carts
  # GET /carts.json
  def index
    @carts = Cart.all
  end

  # GET /carts/1
  # GET /carts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /carts/new
  def new
    @cart = Cart.new
  end

  # GET /carts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /carts
  # POST /carts.json
  def create
    @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /carts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /carts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.update(cart_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /carts/1
  # DELETE /carts/1.json
  def destroy
    @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
    session[:cart_id] = nil
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to store_url, notice: "Your cart is currently empty" }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_cart
      @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def cart_params
      params[:cart]
    end

    def invalid_cart
      logger.error "Attempt to access invalid cart #{params[:id]}"
      redirect_to store_url, notice: "Invalid Cart"
    end
end
```

current_cart.rb

```
module CurrentCart
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  private
    def set_cart
      @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        @cart = Cart.create
        session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    end
end
```

line_item_controller.rb

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /line_items
  # GET /line_items.json
  def index
    @line_items = LineItem.all
  end

  # GET /line_items/1
  # GET /line_items/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /line_items/new
  def new
    @line_item = LineItem.new
  end

  # GET /line_items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /line_items
  # POST /line_items.json
  def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product: product)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /line_items/1
  # DELETE /line_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @line_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to line_items_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_line_item
      @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def line_item_params
      params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id )
    end
end
```

Comment: I would recommend looking at Spree and seeing how they setup the "cart". To me, a user doesn't have many carts, a user has many orders and orders and in varying states such as "complete", "paid", "shipped", and firstly "cart".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Cart.create` and `Cart.find` in **CurrentCart.rb**, you should do something like:

```
def set_cart
  @cart = current_user.carts.find_by(id: session[:cart_id]) || current_user.carts.create
  session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
end
```

`find_by` doesn't throw an error if it can't find it; it just returns nil, so you don't have to worry about rescuing.

Comment: Also, when you log out a user, you should make sure to set `session[:cart_id] = nil`